# Selenium in Python script only works after I have manually clicked element once?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver, hidden

I tried running a move_to_elemen and hover script without anything else and they seem to work:

Well I actually seem to be able to use hover and move_to_element is working... the problem *I Think* is that its going to fast and the next command needs the menu to be visible to work.

Basically my original question is flawed so I will ask something more specific after I try to chain some of this together.

---

Update on the below, it seems it is finding the element but it runs so fast the code below that looks on the menu can't find it.

I have been fighting this for a few weeks and made some progress but I am confused why it works after I have clicked the element(in a previous run) but if I start fresh and run the script it stalls and is unable to find the first element in the chain(menuitem4). The element I am looking for is only visible when menuitem4(settings) is hovered over or clicked by the mouse. If it is pulling this information from browser cache can I artificially put this cache information in the location its scraping/looking?

I now have it to the point where it will wait and if I mouse over the settings dropdown it will automatically go down and find the appropriate button then everything works flawlessly(on first run).  If you guys could help me figure out how to get the mouse to hover over settings somehow I would greatly appreciate it.

I have tried every variation I could find on stackoverflow and other solutions found on google, move_to_element doesn't work.  Also I don't know how valid this is but I read multiple posts indicating hover is broken in python.

the firefox IDE version works flawlessly, you will see some of the random stuff I have tried I could include more stuff I have tried but maybe I am missing something simple.

Here is what I have found that identify's settings:

Unique Selector:

## topMenuItem4 > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)

Outer HTML:

`<span textid="242">Settings</span>`

XPath:

/html/body/div[2]/ul[2]/li[4]/a/span

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import unittest, time, re

class Testpythoncase1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://192.168.0.135"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True
    
    def test_pythoncase1(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/login.htm")
        driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("456")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Submit']").click()
    #driver.implicitly_wait(300)
    settings = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='topMenuItem4']")
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(settings).perform()
    #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='topMenuItem4']/ul/li[6]/a/span").click()
    #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='topMenuItem4']").click()
    #driver.implicitly_wait(300)
    #element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath("settings"))
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='topMenuItem4']/ul/li[6]/a/span"))
    #ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(settings).perform()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='topMenuItem4']/ul/li[6]/a/span").click()
    is_disappeared = WebDriverWait(driver, 30, 1, (ElementNotVisibleException))
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(settings).perform()
    #until_not(lambda x: x.find_element_by_id().is_displayed("//li[@id='topMenuItem4']/ul/li[6]/a/span"))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='topMenuItem4']/ul/li[6]/a/span").click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("297").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("297").send_keys("")
        driver.find_element_by_name("297").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("297").send_keys("192.168.0.10")
        driver.find_element_by_name("305").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("305").send_keys("")
        driver.find_element_by_name("305").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("305").send_keys("poly3")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@onclick='submitForm()']").click()
        #driver.find_element_by_id("popupbtn0").click()
        #driver.close()
    driver.find_element_by_name("30533").send_keys("poly3")
    
    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True
    
    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException, e: return False
        return True
    
    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True
    
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```